# Screen goes blank after selecting DVD from Boot Menu while installing 12.10 on new HP Pavilion

Tags: system-installation, 12.10, windows-8

I'm trying to install the latest 12.10 desktop. I have burned the iso file onto a DVD using an ISO burner. I then reboot my computer, and use the boot menu, I choose the DVD and it asks me if I want to try it, install it, or check for defects. Whichever one I choose, my screen goes blank and for a moment I can hear my DVD burner, but then it stops and the screen goes completely blank and doesn't do anything.

I am using a new HP Pavilion model P7-1455 running Windows 8. What is wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I downloaded the .iso via torrent http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/.  Once that was complete I used imgBurn to put the .iso on a CD.  After that it worked.

If you currently do not have the ability to download a .torrent file I recommend uTorrent 2.0.1.  It's ~313KB and can be downloaded here: http://www.oldapps.com/utorrent.php?old_utorrent=32

Comment: Now its giving me an error, that a file is missing

Comment: Did you check the MD5 checksum? http://download.cnet.com/MD5-Checksum-Calculator/3000-2092_4-10964258.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this issue is still 'open' but I had a very similar experience recently with an HP Pavilion g6 about a month ago.  So I hope my experience helps you to a resolve.  It's a 2 step process:

1. Create a bootable USB (not a DVD which I found to display the missing file error) and then install with the BIOS/EUFI 'Secure boot' setting disabled.  See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227149/how-do-i-install-12-10-on-a-pavilion-g6-laptop-with-uefi) for details.  This gives you an installation of 12.10 which can only be accessed by manually interrupting the boot and selecting 12.10 in GRUB; if you let the machine boot without intervening in this state it will go straight to Win8.  Hence the need for step 2...
2. Open Ubuntu and install/run a program called 'Boot-Repair' using the program's default suggestions.  Details [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228434/how-do-i-boot-hp-pavilion-g6-to-display-grub2-00-rather-than-opening-windows8-by).

Good luck!  I hope all goes well for you.