# Cannot detect Windows 8 from Ubuntu 12.04 Live USB installation on Toshiba qosmio x870

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, live-usb, uefi, windows-8

From other questions raised, I read that if *Ubuntu Live USB* boots in *UEFI* mode then it should detect *Windows 8* during installation. During installation, I only see two options, **Erase disk and install Ubuntu** and **Something else**. I don't want to Erase disk and install Ubuntu but **Install Ubuntu alongside windows 8**. How can I enable the Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD/USB to detect the existing Windows 8? Thanks.

Sorry the latest response.

@[Rod](https://askubuntu.com/users/93977/rod-smith) here are the screenshots as requested:

[image: Installation type]
[image: Partition table]

@[Paddy](https://askubuntu.com/users/2088/paddy-landau) here's the result from running sudo parted --list:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted --list
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  473MB   472MB   ntfs         Basic data partition  hidden, diag
 2      473MB   746MB   273MB   fat32        Basic data partition  boot
 3      746MB   880MB   134MB   ntfs         Basic data partition  msftres
 4      880MB   990GB   989GB   ntfs         Basic data partition
 5      990GB   1000GB  10.4GB  ntfs         Basic data partition  hidden, diag


Model: WD 1600BEV External (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 160GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  160GB  160GB  primary  ntfs


Model: TOSHIBA TOSHIBA USB DRV (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 8011MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4129kB  8011MB  8007MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that Windows 8 is installed with UEFI? If not, you may need to boot Ubuntu normally.

Comment: @Paddy Well, it's a new laptop and when I called Toshiba service, they mentioned UEFI. The initial issue was that Toshiba qosmio x870 that came with windows 8 wasn't detecting Ubuntu Live CD/USB until I disabled the Secure Boot. Now I'm able to boot to Windows 8 with Secure Boot disabled and also boot the Live USB. The problem is that when attempting to install Ubuntu after trying it, it doesn't detect Windows 8. It shows only two options as explained in the question. Can you please explain what you meant by booting Ubuntu normally? Thanks

Comment: Try the "Something Else" option and report on what it's telling you about your partition table. (You needn't install all the way; I just want to know what partitions the installer is seeing, if any.) A damaged partition table could cause the sort of symptom you're seeing, or it could be something else is going on.

Comment: @Mighty: UEFI is pretty new, so there may be some problems. See [question 227149](http://askubuntu.com/questions/227149/how-do-i-install-12-10-on-a-pavilion-g6-laptop-with-uefi). To follow on from @Rod Smith, you could also boot into "Try Ubuntu", open a terminal (press `Ctrl`+`T`), and enter the command `sudo parted --list`. Paste the results here.

Comment: @thakrage I finally decided to _Erase disk and install Ubuntu_. :) Installing other **OS** on a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Mount EFI to /boot/efi but DO NOT FORMAT then after that, mount your other partitions (eg /home /). Install and reboot. You will now boot to Ubuntu so you can configure grub.cfg to be visible and add a Windows option. I have no experience in installing Ubuntu on EFI as I am an Arch user but this should help. 
EDIT

**This will not work if you did not boot Ubuntu from UEFI. To boot DVD/USB in UEFI keep it enabled but disable secure boot option in BIOS.**
Do all as root `sudo -i` or `su root`
List all your partitions with `cat /proc/partitions`
Make an efi directory `mkdir /boot/efi`
Mount your EFI partition eg: `mount /dev/sdX /boot/efi`
Install grub-efi `apt-get install grub-efi`
Finally, install grub. Grub will automatically add option to Firmware Boot Manager.
`grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=Ubuntu --recheck --debug`

Comment: Hello user119808, thanks for your feedback. I would ask that you update your answer and give a detailed solution that other users can read and try based on your experience that works. For example, rather than say mount your other partitions /home/, you should say, 
`mount /home/` and also indicate if a root user or not in which case it would be `sudo mount /home/`. Let the user know that this process is done from the terminal. Also you didn't indicate if the process is done from a live cd/usb and how. Thanks