# Ubuntu 12.10 64bit installation on HP Pavilion g6

Tags: 12.10, system-installation, hp-pavilion

I have been trying to install ubuntu 12.10 - 64 bit in my system with the following config:

```
HP Pavilion G6
Windows 8 - 64bit
8 GB RAM
Intel Core i5
```

I have read a number of articles on internet talking about the it. But the problem with me is I am unable to boot from USB, CD in any case. 
I have `disabled` the `secure mode` settings, and set the correct boot order. After that it never recognizes by connected Flash drive or Live CD. It always boots in windows 8.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know which step I am doing wrong.

Ref:

[Installing Ubuntu on Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

[Secure Boot in Windows 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/12-10-uefi-secure-boot-install)

[Dual Boot with UEFI mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227149/how-do-i-install-12-10-on-a-pavilion-g6-laptop-with-uefi)

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not an Ubuntu but more of a "Had no time to press the KEY that shows the Boot menu". most HP have a special key, might be F2, F10 or even ESC that if you press it when booting it will show you all bootable devices. If the computer is the one you are mentioning, you might have less than a second to do this, so the first second after turning the computer on, you need to start pressing the KEY (Whichever it is). If you burned the image correctly either on the DVD or USB then it should work. The fact that is booting to Win8 just means that it booted too quickly.

Comment: Also. When it boots after a shutdown, it's actually hybernated in Windows 8, and just resumes on boot. So make sure you actually restart and not close/start. :)

Answer (score 0):

At system start,press esc --> f9 and select the boot device

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're still struggling, note that, while in Windows, pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> on my HP pavilion involves pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> key, as the default mode for <kbd>F10</kbd> is to increase the volume.

However, when you're booting, you just need to press <kbd>F10</kbd> without the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to get the BIOS menu, as the Windows override of the function keys hasn't yet kicked in.